# How do I batch decompress so that each file unzips to separate folder?

Tags: windows, zip

Does anyone know how to unzip a highlighted list, so they unzip to folders of file name (under Windows)?

Comment: What OS? What archiving software do you have?

Comment: this ones for windows.

Answer (score 0):

`unzip *`

"unzip" starts a process that unzips, "*" is a glob that passes all file in the current diroctory to the process; hence, all files in the directory are unzipped by the process you start by this command.

It unzips to a folder with the zip's name as the folder name by default.

If you only want to unzip certain files, make the glob more specific; or use `find` with a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with a highlighted list, but in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791568/116891 I have a batch script that will unzip all files in the current directory:

```
:: To actually include the path expansion character (tilde), I had to give valid numbers; see http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html for bug reference. Also, try call /? for more info.
@REM The %~n0 extracts the name sans extension to use as output folder. If you need full paths, use "%~dpn0". The -y forces overwriting by saying yes to everything. Or use -aoa to overwrite.
@REM Using `x` instead of `e` maintains dir structure (usually what we want)

@FOR /R %%a IN (*.zip) DO @(
    @if [%1] EQU [/y] (
        @7z x "%%a" -o"%%~dpna" -aoa
    ) else (
        @echo 7z x "%%a" -o"%%~dpna" -aoa
    )
)

@echo USAGE: Use /y to actually do the extraction
```

If you want a gui to do the unzipping, you can try http://www.extractnow.com/ (as described somewhat at [How can I recursively extract zip files on Windows including deletion?](https://superuser.com/questions/421915/how-can-i-recursively-extract-zip-files-on-windows-including-deletion/422091#422091))