# How to unzip files that have been zipped multiple times?

Tags: macos, command-line, compression, zip

I've been writing a bunch of files to a folder, however this quickly made me almost run out of space, so I decided to zip all the files. However, I messed up and did this multiple times, so some files have 4 .zips (ex *.zip.zip.zip.zip) and others have different amounts. Is there a way/terminal command to make all the files just have 1 .zip? (ex convert a file that is file.zip.zip.zip to file.zip)

Edit: Just to make things clearer, I do not want to unzip all the files, I just want them to all be compressed once.

Comment: Show the code that you ran too. Renaming files is one thing but needing to extract and then keep extracting overwriting dupes, etc. may be needed. Not sure if the code you ran would help but you might as well show what you did that caused this mess. I suppose you don't have file backups and a way to restore, right? I know that'd be too easy if that were the case. Check out my answer here though in case it helps for your immediate need; something to test with at least if nothing else: https://superuser.com/questions/1285257/extract-zip-file-and-then-all-sub-zip-files/1285267#1285267

Comment: Ooops, it looks like you are Mac and not Windows, uh.... I'll leave comment in case it gives ideas to Mac OS experts for something Mac equivalent.

Comment: I guess it might be useful to post what I ran from terminal:  for item in *; do zip -m "${item}.zip" "${item}"; done. I now altered it to only convert non-zip files, but I still am left with about 1000 or so repeated zip files.

Comment: Utilities such as Stuffit Expander [freeware] will keep going until there's nothing left to de-compress.

Comment: @PseudoNym Hi, I'm not a bash expert but should parse the extension `.zip` with `awk` or `sed`, count the repetitions and then un-zip `n-1` given that you have `n` extensions. This idea will work everytime if when you zipped a file added another trailing `.zip` extension. Other technique you could use, is to snoop inside the zip file, and if is there is another zip file decompress. The first idea could be done in a `shell` script. For the second I think it would be easier in another languege like python.